# How to pass activity to formbuilder class in Bot Framework

Tags: bots, botframework, formbuilder

I have below LUIS Dialog class from which I redirect it to formbuilder class, I want to pass a context.Activity to my formbuilder method which and it resides in another class is given right after the code.How to do this?

```
public class LUISManager : LuisDialog<object>
{
    [LuisIntent("BookFlight")]
    public async Task BookFlight(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {    
        //context.Activity       
        FlightBooking cb = new FlightBooking();
        BuildFormDelegate<FlightBooking> MakeFlightBookingForm = FlightBooking.BuildForm;
        var flightBooking = new FormDialog<FlightBooking>(cb, MakeFlightBookingForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, null);
        context.Call<FlightBooking>(flightBooking, FlightBookingComplete);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class FlightBooking
{
public static IForm<FlightBooking> BuildForm()
{
    return new FormBuilder<FlightBooking>().Message("Tell me meeting details!")
    .Field(nameof(title))
    .Field(nameof(StartDate))//, validate: ValidateStartDate
    .Field(nameof(EntryTime), validate:ValidateCallTime)
    .Build();
}
},
```

I know we can pass "IDialogContext context" parameter in BuildForm method but how to pass it from BuildFormDelegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the constructor to:

```
public static IForm<FlightBooking> BuildForm(IDialogContext context)
{}
```

Then you can use a [lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) expression:

```
BuildFormDelegate<FlightBooking> MakeFlightBookingForm = ()=>FlightBooking.BuildForm(context);
```

Comment: Is there more to your scenario?  I tested the code above without issue.

Comment: Hi Eric Dahlvang,
have you tested the code with context parameter to FormBuilder? I got an error. I have added another post on my issue, can you please have a look at it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077629/exception-in-bot-framework-application-in-a-formbuilder-cannot-serialize-deleg/45111955?noredirect=1#comment77242996_45111955