# Exception in BOT Framework application in a FormBuilder : Cannot serialize delegates over unmanaged

Tags: bots, botframework

I am getting  below error in FormFlow.
A quick help is really appreciable.

> Exception: anonymous method closures that capture the environment are
>   not serializable, consider removing environment capture or using a
>   reflection serialization surrogate:
>   FlightBot.FlightManager+<>c__DisplayClass2_0",   "attachments": [
>       {
>         "contentType": "text/plain",
>         "content": "   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Serialization.ClosureCaptureErrorSurrogate.System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializationSurrogate.GetObjectData(Object
>   obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)

After searching on StackOverflow and GitHub I got a piece of a code which says that "You need to register it in autofac container".

So I placed below code in WebAPIConfig.cs

```
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterModule(new ReflectionSurrogateModule());
    builder.Update(Conversation.Container);
```

But still I got an error, but this time error was different compared to previous and it is given below,

> "Exception: Cannot serialize delegates over unmanaged function
>   pointers, dynamic methods or methods outside the delegate creator's
>   assembly.",   "attachments": [
>       {
>         "contentType": "text/plain",
>         "content": "   at System.MulticastDelegate.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info,
>   StreamingContext context)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object
>   obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context,
>   SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter,
>   ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)\r\n

I have copied the complete code of my application over here.

1. First part is MessagesController class from where I call
   FlightManager which is a LUIS dialog.
2. The second part of the code is FlightManager class from where I call
   FlightBooking class.
3. Third is actual flight booking class.

   ```
   [BotAuthentication]
   public class MessagesController : ApiController
   {
       internal static IDialog<object> MakeRootDialog()
       {
           return Chain.From(() => new FlightManager());
       }

       public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
       {
           if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
           {
               await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeRootDialog);
           }
           else
           {
               HandleSystemMessage(activity);
           }
           var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
           return response;
       }

       private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
       {
           if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
           {
               // Implement user deletion here
               // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
           }
           else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
           {
               // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
               // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
               // Not available in all channels
           }
           else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
           {
               // Handle add/remove from contact lists
               // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
           }
           else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
           {
               // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
           }
           else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
           {
           }

           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

---

```
namespace FlightBot
{
    [LuisModel("luis model key", "luis secret")] 
    [Serializable]
    public class FlightManager : LuisDialog<object>
    {
        public async Task FlightBookingTask(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {
            PromptDialog.Confirm(
                context: context,
                resume: ResumeAndHandleConfirmAsync,
                prompt: $"It seems you wish to book a flight. Do you wish to continue?",
                retry: "I didn't understand. Please try again.");
        }

        private async Task ResumeAndHandleConfirmAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> argument)
        {
            FlightBooking cb = new FlightBooking();
            BuildFormDelegate<FlightBooking> MakeFlightBookingForm = () => FlightBooking.BuildForm(context);
            var flightBooking = new FormDialog<FlightBooking>(cb, MakeFlightBookingForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, null);
            context.Call(flightBooking, FlightBookingComplete);
        }

        private async Task FlightBookingComplete(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<FlightBooking> result)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace FlightBot
{
    [Serializable]
    public class FlightBooking
    {
        [Prompt("Enter source :")]
        public string Source { get; set; }

        [Prompt("Enter destination :")]
        public string Destination { get; set; }

        public static IForm<FlightBooking> BuildForm(IDialogContext context)
        {
            return new FormBuilder<FlightBooking>().Message("Tell me about flight details!")
           .Field(nameof(Source))
           .Field(nameof(Destination))
           .Build();

        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Anybody there who can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the first exception and from what I have learned, you cannot send parameters when you call the form builder method in this line:

`BuildFormDelegate<FlightBooking> MakeFlightBookingForm = () => FlightBooking.BuildForm(context);`

So make sure you declare the method without any parameters:

```
public static IForm<FlightBooking> BuildForm()
{ //code   }
```

I hope this could help you, good luck with your bot!

Comment: Hi maria, Thank you for taking your time to read my post.I already had another form in which I m not passing parameter and it is working fine. In this particular case, i am in a need to pass the parameter as I want to store data in UserData of bot, is there any other alternative where we can access UserData in formbuilder without passing context as a parameter?

Comment: I have been looking for ways to pass parameters to the formbuilder method but so far I haven't found a convinient and secure way (you could use "global variables", but using them can cause concurrency issues if many users have conversations with your bot at once so I would not recommend that option). Also, from what I understood in your question, you need save some data to UserData, so did you consider getting the response of your form (after the user answers the last question) to your `FlightBookingComplete` and there you can save the data to the UserData?

Comment: Thank you maria for your valuable time. Below is my scenario, currently we have a web application functionality which we are trying to convert it into BOT. We have a web form in which we have 3 dropdowns and every succeeding dropdown is dependant on the previous selection and all those dropdown data is coming from SQL DB. So on the selection of the first dropdown I have certain List<CommonFields> which I want to bind it to the second dropdown, since we can't mention List<Class> in Formbuilder, So I want to save these list to UserData. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I see now; well my suggestion is, maybe you could simulate the form using dialogs, that way you could access these Lists in the dialog methods and display the List options using a card, you could work and use a bit of programming logic to accomplish what you need haha. For example, you say you have 3 dropdowns, so you can make 3 dialogs, and each of them checks the user messagee to guide the dialog and use the correct List of options from each dropdown during the conversation.

Comment: Since FormFlow is a neat and clean way of achieving the conversation, that's why I was trying hard to achieve the same.My last option was to try with dialog and I think the time has come :-). I will explore dialogs. Anyway, thanks. still, hope is alive.